# How to change Google Keyboard appearance programmatically?

Tags: java, android, android-softkeyboard, android-source

Is it possible with root (better without) to change the appearance of the Google keyboard (AOSP) programmatically from light to dark? 
I couldn't find any documentation on this, so I'm not even sure if it's possible

Answer (score 0):

The AOSP keyboard ( not the be confused with GBoard, Google's new keyboard app) is the LatinIME module found here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/inputmethods/LatinIME/+/refs/heads/master

Go to resources of that module (/res/values) and theme it as you wish.

Comment: So I would need to recompile this module or I should edit some system files on my device?

Comment: Yes, I meant to make changes there, recompile and flash